Does a remainder participation number needed to be updated via backend and database?
I am developing a workshop registration web application based on Reactjs, MySQL and Nodejs/PHP. There are different maximum number of participation for each workshop. So once a participant pick a specific workshop, the participation number of corresponding workshop will be deducted one.
So far, I am using Context API and useReducer to manage the state (add a workshop, remove a workshop). And the logic of add/remove a workshop is done by userReducer. This maximum number of participation should be reactively seen by the users on the web application as well. My question is, should I somehow update this "number" to the database in order to update it globally? Because there are various users will register the same workshop, so this number should be extracted from database to ensure it is the latest one.
Sorry if I asked a relatively stupid question. I am just confused.

There can be multiple options to consider depending on different scenarios. May be what you are using is also correct depending on importance of your application. May be you want to keep up to date your database on every call then update user interface or you can update user interface then update database. It's all depends what approach is suitable for your application. I can list few.

Database Updates You can indeed update the maximum number of participants for each workshop in the database whenever a participant registers for a workshop. This ensures that the data is always up-to-date and reflects the current state accurately. However, frequent database updates can potentially affect performance, especially if there are many users registering for workshops simultaneously.
Optimistic Updates You can also implement optimistic updates on the client side. When a participant registers for a workshop, you can immediately update the UI to reflect the change (e.g., decrement the available slots) without waiting for confirmation from the server. Then, in the background, you can send the registration request to the server and update the database. If the server returns an error (e.g., if the workshop is already full), you can revert the UI to its original state
Real-Time Updates if real-time updates are important for your application, you can consider implementing WebSocket or Server-Sent Events (SSE) to push updates from the server to the client whenever the maximum number of participants for a workshop changes. This way, participants can see the latest information without needing to refresh the page.

